# Render SSRS 2008 Report in web page without Report Viewer

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a web app written in C# that I need to be able to render an `SSRS` report on an aspx page *without using the Report Viewer control.*

As HTML inside a div tag would be perfect.  I have the app attached to my `SSRS` instance via `ReportingService2010` reference.

I've found some examples online but are for `ReportingServices2005` and couldn't port them over.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I pulled this out of a project I put together about a year ago.

A few key points:

- you need to pass credentials to the report server.
- you need to create an images path so that any images in your report are rendered and displayed in  the html Report/GraphFiles/ "this should be relative to your app url"
- and if your report has any parameters you will need to add them.
- you will definitely need to tweek the code to get it going.

it uses the ReportExecutionService reference, you will have to play around with it but the nuts and bolts should all be here.

i'd really love to spend time cleaning it up a bit but i dont have the time sorry, i hope it helps

```
class RenderReport
    {

        public struct ReportServerCreds
            {
                public string UserName { get; set; }
                public string Password { get; set; }
                public string Domain { get; set; }

            }

            public ReportServerCreds GetReportCreds()
            {

                ReportServerCreds rsc = new ReportServerCreds();
                rsc.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reportserveruser"].ToString();
                rsc.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reportserverpassword"].ToString();
                rsc.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reportserverdomain"].ToString();

                return rsc;
            }

           public enum SSRSExportType
            { 
                HTML,PDF
            }

            public string RenderReport(string reportpath,SSRSExportType ExportType)
            {
                using (ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient res = new   ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient("ReportExecutionServiceSoap"))
                {

                    ReportExecutionService.ExecutionHeader ExecutionHeader = new ReportExecutionService.ExecutionHeader();
                    ReportExecutionService.TrustedUserHeader TrusteduserHeader = new ReportExecutionService.TrustedUserHeader();

                    res.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

                    ReportServerCreds rsc = GetReportCreds();
                    res.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = rsc.Domain;
                    res.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = rsc.UserName;
                    res.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = rsc.Password;


                    res.Open();
                    ReportExecutionService.ExecutionInfo ei = new ReportExecutionService.ExecutionInfo();

                    string format =null;
                    string deviceinfo =null;
                    string mimetype = null;

                    if (ExportType.ToString().ToLower() == "html")
                    {
                        format = "HTML4.0";
                        deviceinfo = @"<DeviceInfo><StreamRoot>/</StreamRoot><HTMLFragment>True</HTMLFragment></DeviceInfo>";
                    }
                    else if (ExportType.ToString().ToLower() == "pdf")
                    {
                        format = "PDF";
                        mimetype = "";
                    }


                    byte[] results = null;
                    string extension = null;
                    string Encoding = null;
                    ReportExecutionService.Warning[] warnings;
                    string[] streamids = null;
                    string historyid = null;
                    ReportExecutionService.ExecutionHeader Eheader;
                    ReportExecutionService.ServerInfoHeader serverinfoheader;
                    ReportExecutionService.ExecutionInfo executioninfo;



                    // Get available parameters from specified report.
                    ParameterValue[] paramvalues = null;
                    DataSourceCredentials[] dscreds = null;
                    ReportParameter[] rparams = null;

                    using (ReportService.ReportingService2005SoapClient lrs = new ReportService.ReportingService2005SoapClient("ReportingService2005Soap"))
                    {


                        lrs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
                        lrs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = rsc.Domain;
                        lrs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = rsc.UserName;
                        lrs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = rsc.Password;


                        lrs.GetReportParameters(reportpath,historyid,false,paramvalues,dscreds,out rparams);

                    }



                    // Set report parameters here
                    //List<ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue> parametervalues = new List<ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue>();

                    //string enumber = Session["ENumber"] as string;
                    //parametervalues.Add(new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue() { Name = "ENumber", Value = enumber });

                    //if (date != null)
                    //{
                    //    DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
                        //parametervalues.Add(new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue() { Name = "AttendanceDate", Value = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")});
                    //}

                    //if (ContainsParameter(rparams, "DEEWRID"))
                    //{
                        //parametervalues.Add(new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue() { Name = "DEEWRID", Value = deewrid });
                    //}

                    //if (ContainsParameter(rparams, "BaseHostURL"))
                    //{
//                        parametervalues.Add(new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue() { Name = "BaseHostURL", Value = string.Concat("http://", Request.Url.Authority) });
                    //}


                    //parametervalues.Add(new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue() {Name="AttendanceDate",Value=null });
                    //parametervalues.Add(new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue() { Name = "ENumber", Value = "E1013" });



                    try
                    {

                        Eheader = res.LoadReport(TrusteduserHeader, reportpath, historyid, out serverinfoheader, out executioninfo);
                        serverinfoheader = res.SetExecutionParameters(Eheader, TrusteduserHeader, parametervalues.ToArray(), null, out executioninfo);
                        res.Render(Eheader, TrusteduserHeader, format, deviceinfo, out results, out extension, out mimetype, out Encoding, out warnings, out streamids);

                        string exportfilename = string.Concat(enumber, reportpath);

                        if (ExportType.ToString().ToLower() == "html")
                        {
                            //write html
                            string html = string.Empty;
                            html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(results);

                            html = GetReportImages(res, Eheader, TrusteduserHeader, format, streamids, html);

                            return html;
                        }
                        else if (ExportType.ToString().ToLower() == "pdf")
                        {
                            //write to pdf


                            Response.Buffer = true;
                            Response.Clear();
                            Response.ContentType = mimetype;



                            //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.pdf", exportfilename));
                            Response.BinaryWrite(results);
                            Response.Flush();
                            Response.End();

                        }


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Response.Write(e.Message);
                    }
                }

            }


            string GetReportImages(ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient res, 
                                   ReportExecutionService.ExecutionHeader EHeader,
                                    ReportExecutionService.TrustedUserHeader tuh,
                                   string reportFormat, string[] streamIDs, string html)
            {
                if (reportFormat.Equals("HTML4.0") && streamIDs.Length > 0)
                {
                    string devInfo;
                    string mimeType;
                    string Encoding;
                    int startIndex;
                    int endIndex;
                    string fileExtension = ".jpg";

                    string SessionId;

                    Byte[] image;

                    foreach (string streamId in streamIDs)
                    {
                        SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("}", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("-", "");
                        //startIndex = html.IndexOf(streamId);
                        //endIndex = startIndex + streamId.Length;

                        string reportreplacementname = string.Concat(streamId, "_", SessionId, fileExtension);
                        html = html.Replace(streamId, string.Concat(@"Report\GraphFiles\", reportreplacementname));


                        //html = html.Insert(endIndex, fileExtension);
                        //html = html.Insert(startIndex, @"Report/GraphFiles/" + SessionId + "_");

                        devInfo = "";
                        //Image = res.RenderStream(reportFormat, streamId, devInfo, out encoding, out mimeType);
                        res.RenderStream(EHeader,tuh, reportFormat, streamId, devInfo, out image , out Encoding, out mimeType);



                        System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Report\\GraphFiles\\" + reportreplacementname);
                        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                        stream.Close();
                        mimeType = "text/html";
                    }
                }

                return html;
            }

            bool ContainsParameter(ReportParameter[] parameters, string paramname)
            {
                    if(parameters.Where(i=>i.Name.Contains(paramname)).Count() != 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
    }
```

To Execute:

first parameter is the location of the report on the server.
the second is a SSRSExportType enum

```
RenderReport("ReportPathOnServer",SSRSExportType.HTML);
```

Comment: Is this for SQL 2008 R2?  I pasted this into a new page in my project and there is a ton of incompatibility.

Comment: Greetings, I have a similar implementation. I am coming across an issue when I load the report from a temp file with images from the same domain in an iframe. The SSRS generated js for image resizing is not working correctly. The resize function seems to run before the image is loaded. Did you by any chance come across similar issues?

Comment: sounds like you need to embed that bit of javascript in a document ready function eg http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/632672/JavaScripts-document-ready-vs-window-load

Comment: Many thanks, I based my solution on this. To avoid writing the images to the disk (and setting permissions, etc), I just converted then to Base64 and embedded them into the HTML img tag's src attribute, which works very well (and allows you to save the html as a file from your browser and then email to somebody else, etc). It works fine in IE, FF and Chrome.  I just got the image string using:  var imageString = "data:image/" + imageFormat + ";base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(image);   and then called html = html.Replace("/" + streamId, imageString);  Image format comes from bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to show the HTML render of a report and you want it to look like a native object to the application without any parameters or toolbar, then you could call the URL for the report directly and include "&rc:Toolbar=false" in the URL.  This will hide the toolbar for the Report Viewer control.  This method is described under the [URL Access Parameter Reference msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx).  Not exactly what you asked for, but it may achieve the purpose.

Here's a sample call that omits the HTML and Body sections if you are embedding the results in an existing HTML document:

```
http://ServerName/ReportServer?%2fSome+Folder%2fSome+Report+Name&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:HTMLFragment=true
```

Comment: I cannot use the Report Viewer control.  I need to embed the report into an existing page & form, without using RV control.

Comment: Is there a reason URL access won't work?  I've embedded reports in existing applications this way more than a dozen times over the years.

Comment: It's the report viewer control that is the issue.  Having an ActiveX control is not allowed on the customer's browser.  I can render within an iframe without the RV control but that requires a form inside the page form and that's obviously not allowed.  No way to use URL access to return a stream of HTML??

Comment: Using URL's you can force rendering without having to embed a report viewer controller.  It just renders the report to HTML on the server and returns the HTML rendered document.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for and have been trying to accomplish.  Can I see an example?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155046.aspx and the link I provided in the response.  The link in this comment provides an example of how to render to an image format.  I'll post a sample HTML render momentarily.

Comment: Added the example to the answer.

Comment: Okay I understand the URL, I can build that up without a problem.  When the HTML is returned, how is it returned?  Is it in a stream that I need to Response.BinaryWrite?  This is the specific part I've been having an issue with.

Comment: It is returned like any other web page you call.  In some applications, the web pages were consumed using a web request / web response.  In other applications, the pages were placed in iframes.

Comment: Still have a mental block on this.  I build up the URL in my codebehind, still cant figure out how to load the returned html into a div on the page.

Comment: Got further, using a WebRequest and GetResponseStream into a StreamReader works - but only when accessing the base lost of reports.  It renders that page in my div.  However when I extend the URL to point to a specific report ex.  xx.xx.xx.xx/reportserver?/My+Reports/the-report   Throws a 500 error.   This happens even when passing in box Admin credentials.

Comment: "When you access a report server or Report Manager through its URL, the URL should include the host name and not the IP address."  From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261.aspx.

Comment: "rc:Toolbar=false does not work for URL access strings that use an IP address, instead of a domain name, to target a report hosted on a SharePoint site."  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx.  Not sure if you are using a SharePoint integrated instance of SSRS.

Comment: I'm actually OK with the toolbar showing, and the reporting services server is only accessible via IP as of this time.  Do you think that would cause the 500 error?  If I shorten the URL I can see the list of reports on the server.  But if I add the report name to the URL is when I get the 500 error even when passing box admin credentials in the NetworkCredential.

Comment: Can you do this without using the IP address?  Can you use the domain name of the server instead?  Or the fully qualified domain name?  I'm pretty sure this will resolve your problem.

Comment: You can try this as solution.  Go to the ReportServer url.  Run the report.  Once it renders, modify the URL to include &rc:Toolbar=false.  Run the report and verify it work.  Copy the full URL that is in your browser and test that with your application.

Comment: That does not work.  If I modify the URL in the URL Access syntax and put it into the browser address bar it automatically redirects to use the Report Viewer control URL like:  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMy+Reports%2fThe-Report&rs:Command=Render   Still cannot get URL Access to work.  I can cut the URL back and see the reports listed but accessing a specific report still says Unauthorized in the debugger.  Even with box admin rights, even with the report Datasource credentials hard coded to the box admin account in BIS.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an old question but if you're using ASP.NET MVC you could try [this open source solution](https://github.com/armanio123/ReportViewerForMvc).  It uses an HTML helper and renders an `.aspx` page in an iframe.  The repo has a server-side, local render, and anonymous example.